# Tegola: Write config file for tables having ' - ' and capital letters in their name

Tags: vector-tiles

I am trying to write a config file contains tables having hyphen character ' - ' and capital letters in their name. But its failed with the following error:

tegola-server | Error: could not register providers: could not generate sql, for layer(Registered_Parks_and_Gardens): ERROR: relation "registered_parks_and_gardens" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01).

Or:

tegola-server | Error: could not register providers: could not generate sql, for layer(civil-parish): ERROR: syntax error at or near "-" (SQLSTATE 42601).

I search through internet but unable to find any solution. Any thoughts on this?